# searching in vim with only 1 match in a line

Tags: search, vim

I want to search a pattern in vim such that if a pattern appears multiple times in a line then it should search that pattern only 1 times in that line and after it match next line.

Is there any way to do it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow your pattern with `.*` which will cause the pattern to match the remainder of a line where it is found. The search for the next pattern starts after the *end* of the last found pattern.

Comment: Accepted this answer as cursor on searching remains on matched line

Answer (score 7):

```
/pattern you want to match/1
```

this tells vim to move down a line before finding the next match.

Answer (score 0):

Try :set nogdefault

Because:

*'gdefault'* *'gd'* *'nogdefault'* *'nogd'*
  'gdefault' 'gd'         boolean (default off)

When on, the ":substitute" flag 'g' is default on.  This means that all matches in a line are substituted instead of one.  When a 'g' flag is given to a ":substitute" command, this will toggle the substitution of all or one match.